# Avoid increased runtime when opening threads in consecutive runs

Tags: python, performance, testing, embedded, python-multithreading

I'm doing my final thesis and my topic is the creation of a software that will run and control an on-satellite experiment.

For that reason, I had to implement the reading of multiple sensors while the experiment is running. To do that, **I wrote the code so that it will create a new thread for each sensor** (multiprocessing might not work because I don't yet know which system the software will run on and therefore I can't say if there will be multiple processors available) and these threads run as daemons all the while the software does its thing. **It works well, but now I need to test the whole thing and this is where it gets problematic**:

To properly test each and every route the software could take, I have multiple variables that need to be set and so there will be a lot of test runs (I calculated around 17.000 but could be wrong). **While the first few test runs go over quickly, each run takes longer and longer**. I have fiddled around with my code a little bit and it turns out that **without threading, each test takes about the same time**. Unfortunately, I do not know why and my knowledge of the matter is very limited. The code concerning the threading is as follows:

This sets up the creation of each thread (`sensor_list` will be populated with multiple sensors in non-test conditions)

```
sensor_list = [<a single sensor>]
        for sensor in sensor_list:
            thread = threading.Thread(
                target=self.store_sensor_data,
                args=[sensor, query_frequency],
                daemon=True,
                name=f"Thread_{sensor}",
            )
            self.threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()
```

The function which actually deals with getting and writing the sensor data, `self.store_sensor_data`, looks like this:

```
def store_sensor_data(self, sensor, frequency):
        """Get the current reading and result from 'sensor' and store them.

        sensor (Sensor) -  the sensor whose data shall be stored
        frequency (int) - the frequency (in 1/s) at which data shall be stored
        """
        value_id = 0
        while not self.HALT:
            value_id += 1
            sensor_reading = sensor.get_reading()
            sensor_result = sensor.get_result()
            try:
                # if there already is a list for that sensor, append the data to it
                self.experiment_report.sensor_data_raw[str(sensor)].append(
                    (value_id, sensor_reading)
                )
            except KeyError:
                # if there is no list, create one containing the current sensor value
                self.experiment_report.sensor_data_raw[str(sensor)] = [
                    (value_id, sensor_reading)
                ]
            # repeat the same for the 'result'
            try:
                self.experiment_report.sensor_data[str(sensor)].append(
                    (value_id, sensor_result)
                )
            except KeyError:
                self.experiment_report.sensor_data[str(sensor)] = [
                    (value_id, sensor_result)
                ]
            time.sleep(1 / frequency)
```

after the experiment is done, I stop the threads by calling

```
def interrupt_sensor_data_recording(self):
        """Interrupt the storing of sensor data by ending all daemon threads.

        threads (list) - a list of currently running threads
        """
        if len(self.threads) > 0:
            self.HALT = True
            for thread in self.threads:
                if thread.is_alive():
                    logger.debug(f"Stopping thread '{thread.getName()}'")
                    thread.join()
                else:
                    thread.join()
                    logger.debug(f"Thread '{thread.getName()}' was already stopped")
```

Now I am unsure if how I stop the daemon threads is appropriate and this might be the source of my problems. But there also might be some implication that I don't know about yet and in both cases, it would be nice if someone with more knowledge than me could help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the embedded OS ?

Comment: Yet to be determined so I am writing on a Windows PC (shame, I know :D)

Comment: "without threading, each test takes about the same time". Do you mean you removed the threads from your code or you implemented the thread code but sequential way ?

Comment: I simply commented out the thread.start() inside the for-loop (the first code snipped in my question)